# Is it possible to search the print spool file based on the printer info?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Windows server 2012 r2 contains spool files with .spl and .shd extension.Just interested to know if there is any way to search print queue of a printer and the related spool files for that printer in the spool directory.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve (i.e., what's provoking the question)?

Comment: sometimes to delete a hung print queue i need to delete all the spool files in order to clear a stuck job in just 1 printer.wonder if i can identify the particular file and just remove that one and leave the rest untouched.

Comment: Through WMI you can at least check the print queue of a printer:

https://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/21/viewing-print-queue-statistics-with-powershell/

Comment: This is more of a [SuperUser] kind of question.  You don't have an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to stop the spooler each time, then simply create a batch file and add:

```
net stop spooler 
del c:\path\to\shd_files\*.shd 
del c:\path\to\spl_files\*.spl 
net start spooler
```